# Bluetooth headphones won't connect

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I have tried and tried to connect my headphones to my laptop, to no avail.  everything else connects with no issues.  the laptop finds the headphones, but will not allow me to connect to them.  any Ideas?

Comment: Please give more details about the headphones, the Ubuntu release and the Bluetooth dongle or Bluetooth-capable computer (mostly the WiFi module) you're using. It could be a hardware issue (try another dongle in that case) or a software bug. But I'm not sure.

Comment: I am using a dongle to pair my headset to the laptop. There haven't been any issues pairing any other devices such as my phone, tablet, keyboard or mouse. It will find the headset, recognize it as a headset,  but won't allow me to connect to it.  I've checked it on my son's laptop, running Windows 7 professional and it's fine.  So there is no compatibility issue there. The bluetooth dongle and the headset are both generic.

Answer (score 0):

Did you pair the headphones with the laptop beforehand?
When you say "connect" do you mean to establish a bluetooth connection or to change the audio output in sound settings. If you mean to latter had a similar issue when I was running ubuntu 13.04 on my laptop. After several attempts to fix it I threw in the towel and downgraded to 12.04. Since then I have had no bluetooth related issues.

Comment: Found that as long as I'm using headphones with no mic is ok,  but regardless of what brand of headphones in using,  if there is a mic,  they won't connect...